# Why do I get this error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' where the get function is on a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
fruits = {
"apple": ["red", "juicy"]
}
```

This `fruits` dictionary is passed and returned in many functions. I am not sure why but in this line of code I get an `AttributeError`.

```
def get_dict(dict):
    dictionary = dict
    appels_attributes = dictionary.get("apple")
    return apples_attributes

print(get_dict(fruits))
```

Is there something wrong or I missed something?

Comment: It works as expected once you remove the typo 'appels_attributes' / 'apples_attributes'. Please provide a [mcve]. When it gets passed to this function, `fruits` is probably no longer what you think it is.

Comment: Please don't name your variables same as python `builtin`s. Use some other name for your `dict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to check your syntax.
In your code:

```
def get_dict(dict):
    dictionary = dict
    appels_attributes = dictionary.get("apple")
    # appels and apples are not equal.
    return apples_attributes
```

I think you've Done some spelling mistake.
Line No 3 : appels
Line No 4: apples

So only one variable was defined. And that was "appels_attributes", And you returned "apples.attributes" which was not defined.
That's why you are getting Attribute Error.

And also don't use any reserved syntax such as "dict" Those are predefined by python.